# Rails test for key in hstore column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hstore

I have a Rails 4 app where the model `Vehicle` has an hstore column called `data`.  The app is also using `gem 'acts_as_tenant'`. The model `Tenant` also has an hstore column called `data`.

What I'm doing is storing user defined fields in Tenant for the Vehicle table.  In other words if the Tenant data (hstore) column contains 'color', then I want every Vehicle to have that same key in their data (hstore) column.

This is the code for the Vehicle form:

```
   <% if current_tenant.data.present? %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :data do |d| %>
            <% current_tenant.data.each do |key, value| unless ???????@vehicle.data%>
                <div class="row">
                  <p class='col-md-3'>
                    <%= text_field_tag key, key, :class => 'text_field dynamicAttributeName' %>
                  </p>
                  <p class='col-md-3'>
                    <%= d.text_field key, :class => 'text_field', :value => value %>
                  </p>
                  <p class='col-md-1'>
                    <a herf='#' class='btn removeRow'>X</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <%- end -%>
    <% end %>

    <% if @vehicle.data.present? %>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :data do |d| %>
            <% @vehicle.data.each do |key, value| %>
                <div class="row">
                  <p class='col-md-3'>
                    <%= text_field_tag key, key, :class => 'text_field dynamicAttributeName' %>
                  </p>
                  <p class='col-md-3'>
                    <%= d.text_field key, :class => 'text_field', :value => value %>
                  </p>
                  <p class='col-md-1'>
                    <a herf='#' class='btn removeRow'>X</a>
                  </p>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <%- end -%>
    <% end %>
```

My issue is the line `<% current_tenant.data.each do |key, value| unless ???????`

I don't want to add the same key twice. So, if the Vehicle data field already has `color`, I don't want to add it again.

How do I test the Vehicle.data field to see if it has a key equal to the `current_tenant.data.each do |key, value|`.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its core, an hstore column defined on a Rails model via `store_accessor :data` acts just like a hash does, as you've seen.

You could do a simple check to see if the `vehicle.data` hash has the key you are looking for.

Something like:

```
current_tenant.data.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} => #{value}" unless vehicle.data.key?(key)
end
```

would print the key value pair unless the vehicle hstore column also had the same key